# Youtube-DL.exe Closes After Launching Command Line

Tags: c++, command-line, youtube, youtube-dl

I've used YouTube-dl successfully on my mac for quite some time.

I downloaded `YouTube-dl.exe` (after downloading Microsoft Visual C++ I was told a newer version already exists on my computer - it also says Python is not required), but when I launch the executable, it briefly opens a command line window but then closes immediately and nothing else happens. I've tried Googling and even went to the `IRC` support chat (who turned out to be more rude than helpful) to no avail. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: This is off-topic, see [help/on-topic]

Comment: Its a software tool that even has its own tag on here.  How is it off topic?

Comment: The tag is for _developing_ youtube-dl. The website in general is about programming, not customer service.

Comment: Search YouTube-dl on here and there are plenty of questions about it

Comment: The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/youtube-dl/info) said it __explicitly__ _"Note that questions about installing and using youtube-dl are off-topic for Stack Overflow. They may be more appropriate on SuperUser."_

Comment: Thats fair.  But there are still many questions about YouTube-dl support here so I won't delete the post.  I'd delete the tag if it would let me.

Comment: You [edit] your question to remove tags. That said, the question won't become on-topic just because you removed the tag. I don't know about the 
rude IRC support chat, but that is your best bet. Or maybe SuperUser, but I'm not familiar with that

Comment: The rude IRC chat is because its a noob question.  Typical of the internet.  Now that I know to treat it just like I would using Terminal in Mac, everything works like I thought it would.

Answer (score 1):

youtube-dl is a command-line application. To use it directly, start a terminal windows by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and entering `cmd`. To get to know the command-line interface, you probably want to consult [a tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/intro_to_command_line/).

If you were looking for a graphical application, use one of the graphical frontends instead; for instance, [youtube-dlg](https://mrs0m30n3.github.io/youtube-dl-gui/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I try opening it on the command line and cd to the folder, then attempt to run it using start youtube-dl.exe - another command line window opens temporarily then closes...

Comment: Wait, I need to probably treat it just like I would using it in Terminal on a mac...